# CSS grid unwanted whitespace in portrait mode

Tags: html, css, css-grid

I am developing a web app for Android. Playing around with CSS grid I want two ‘Views’ on for landscape and one for portrait. The layout mainly consists of a Product display and a menu (with mostly buttons). In portrait mode the menu should be displayed under the product (which is working fine). The problem is that there is a massive withspace at the left in the grid holding the product and menu divs. I also would like the grid to wrap around the product. I use a server so load the product into the wrapper div.

The wanted behaviour for portrait would be that the product and menu are aligned to the left and their width adjusted to the width of the product.
[image]

```css
    .hide {
      display: none;
    }
    
    @media only screen and (orientation: portrait) {
      .grid {
        display: grid;
        grid-template-rows: [wrapper] auto [menu] auto;
      }
    } 
    
    @media only screen and (orientation: landscape) {
      body {
          background-color: lightblue;
      }
      .grid {
        display: grid;
        grid-template-columns: [wrapper] auto [menu] auto 1fr;
      }
    
      .menu{
        grid-area: menu;
        border-style: solid;
        display:grid;
        grid-template-rows: repeat(auto); 
      }  
    }
    
    .product {
      display: inline-grid;
      grid-template-columns: auto auto;
      grid-template-rows: repeat(6,[row] auto);
      padding: 5px;
    }
    .wrapper{
      grid-area: wrapper;
      border-style: solid;
      
    }
    .menu{
      grid-area: menu;
      border-style: solid;
    }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
        <head>
            <title>test CSS Grid</title>
            <link media="all" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="product.css">
            <script src = "jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
            <script type="text/javascript" src="productScript.js"></script>
            <div class="hide">
                <div id="product" class="product">
                    <div><u>Pos: </u></div><div class="Pos">test1</div>
                    <div><u>Artikel: </u></div><div class="Artikel">test2</div>
                    <div><u>Menge: </u></div><input class="Menge" type="text" />
                    <div><u>Lagerplatz: </u></div><div class="Lagerplatz">test6</div>
                    <div><u>Bezeichnung: </u></div><div class="Bezeichnung">test3</div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </head>
        <body>
            <div class="grid">
                <div id="wrapper" class="wrapper">
                </div>
                <div class="menu">
                    <button type="button" onclick="mockConfirm()"> barcode</button>
                    <button type="button" onclick="cancelPicklist()"> cancel</button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </body>
    </html>
```

Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you need to use `display:inline-grid` instead and you only need two columns in the `product` div.

```css
.product {
  display: inline-grid;
  grid-template-columns: auto auto;
  background: lightgreen;
}

.grid {
  margin: 1em;
  display: inline-grid;
  background: pink;
  border: 1px solid grey;
}
```

```html
<div class="grid">
  <div id="wrapper" class="wrapper">
    <div id="product" class="product">
      <div><u>Pos: </u></div>
      <div class="Pos">test1</div>
      <div><u>Artikel: </u></div>
      <div class="Artikel">Lorem, ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit.</div>
      <div><u>Menge: </u></div><input class="Menge" type="text" />
      <div><u>Lagerplatz: </u></div>
      <div class="Lagerplatz">test6</div>
      <div><u>Bezeichnung: </u></div>
      <div class="Bezeichnung">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="menu">
    <button type="button" onclick="mockConfirm()"> barcode</button>
    <button type="button" onclick="cancelPicklist()"> cancel</button>
  </div>
</div>
```